# jsoup does not delete elements

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm here again.

i got this piece of code:

```
this.doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
        Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
        if(tables!=null){
            for(Element table : tables){
                if(table != null){
                    Elements tds=table.getElementsByTag("td");
                    if(tds!=null){
                        for(Element td : tds){
                            String[] text=td.text().trim().split("\\s+");
                            if(text.length<2)td.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Elements hs = doc.getElementsByTag("h1, h2, h3, h4");
        if(hs!=null)for(Element h : hs)if(h != null)h.remove();
        Elements blocks = doc.getElementsByTag("div, center, li, p, address, aside, audio, blockquote, canvas, dd, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, header, hr, hgroup, li, ol, noscript, output, pre, section");
        if(blocks!=null){
            System.out.println(blocks.size());
            for(Element block : blocks){
                if(block != null){
                    String[] text=block.text().trim().split("\\s+");
                    if(text.length<2)block.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        Elements pdp = doc.getElementsByClass("pineDeletePoint");
        if(pdp!=null&&pdp.size()>0)pdp.remove();
        str = this.doc.outerHtml();
```

however i still have block elements which have less than two words inside among my html.

why i cant delete them?

thanks a lot for you help...

Comment: sorry my previous answer had a little error in the regular expression. updated it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
Elements hs = doc.getElementsByTag("h1, h2, h3, h4");
```

I understand what you want but passing multiple tag separated by `,` won't work with `getElementsByTag()`, it works with `select()` function e.g.,  `doc.select("div, h1, h2")`. However i can think of a solution using  **Pseudo selector** `:matchesOwn(regex)` with reges: `^\s*\S+\s*$`. Here is a short working example:

```
    String data = "<div>  asd asd</div><span><p>  asdd </p></span>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
    Elements elms = doc.select(":matchesOwn(^\\s*\\S+\\s*$)");
          // do whatever you are going to do with elms
    System.out.println(elms);  // print the elements having less than two words
    elms.remove(); // remove all elements from document which contains 
                   //  less than 2 words in their own text  
    System.out.println("\nprinting Document:\n"+doc);
```

And the output:

```
     <p> asdd </p>

printing Document:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
    asd asd
  </div>
  <span></span>
 </body>
</html>
```